# A pop-up preventing a JS file from loading

Tags: javascript

I just implemented a items slider on my website. I used a free hosting service (000webhost) to put my website online so that I will be able to test it on different devices.
What I noticed is that, when you open my website ([Link to my website](http://jeannot.comli.com)) for the first time, a pop-up coming from the free hosting service will be displayed:

[image: pop-up coming from the free hosting service]

And after closing the pop-up, the items slider looks like this, which is not normal:

[image: when there is the pop-up]

Then you need to refresh the page, and when there is no pop-up, you will see the normal display:
[image: when there is no pop-up]

Any time the slider is not normally displayed, the slider does not work perfectly.
I think that the pop-up is preventing the loading of certain of my JavaScript files.

This is the code concerning the items slider:

```html
<div class="clearfix">
   <h1>Femme <span>Les articles feminins viennent à vous</span></h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
   <div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01"><h4>Boots</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02"><h4>Oxfords</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03"><h4>Loafers</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="img04"><h4>Sneakers</h4></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"><h4>Belts</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="img06"><h4>Hats &amp; Caps</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="img07"><h4>Sunglasses</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="img08"><h4>Scarves</h4></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="img09"><h4>Casual</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt="img10"><h4>Luxury</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/11.jpg" alt="img11"><h4>Sport</h4></a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <nav>
     <a href="#">Chaussures</a>
     <a href="#">Acccesoires</a>
     <a href="#">Vêtements</a>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!-- /container -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.catslider.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {

   $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider();

  });
 </script>
```

Please help me know how I can solve this problem that I am facing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the popup created? I can't see it in the code you've posted.

Comment: I'm assuming the hosting company attaches some sort of wrapper or injects a script which shows the popup? P. Lionel can you investigate where the code is that is injecting the popup and show that in your question?

Comment: @ManoDestra, I am not the one, genereating the pop-up, it is generated by the hosting compay

Comment: Check the generated source, in that case, and see the code that's being injected by the hosting company regarding ads. You may have to be careful regarding putting variable names in the global space. Their external code may be overwriting them. Or their HTML injection into your pages may be killing it stone dead and there's little recourse, but to seek assistance from the hosting company themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot check it on your added snippet. But what I am guessing is there is a conflict between two `jQuery` versions. Try adding the blow line at the top of your jQuery code event before `ready()` function.

```
$.noConflict();
```

Also notice in the image that there are two jQuery versions loading.

First time:
[image: The First visit, when the popup is loading.]

Second time:
[image: Second time, when the popup is not loading anymore.]

More information in **[jQuery website](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)**

Comment: Thanks @Roy for providing your help.

Before saying anything, I have to confess that my knowledge in `jquery` is very limited and also I am not a native English speaker.

I was trying to use your solution to solve my problem but there is an issue. I have three `.js file` affecting my items slider: `jquery.catslider.js` , `modernizr.custom.63321.js` and `jquery.min.js` .

I check the three and I do not get the right place to insert the following line `$.noConflict();`

Can you provide your help, one more time ;)

Comment: You have to add it before your custom script. In you case I would guess it's inside `<script>` tag. `$.noConflict(); $(function() {

   $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider();

  });`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and come again to give a feedback

Comment: I have done what you said but nothing new. Any different suggestion ?

Comment: Well in that case try replacing all the `$` with `jQuery` in  `jquery.catslider.js` and inside your `<script>` tag. e.g. like this, `jQuery( '#mi-slider' ).catslider();`

Answer (score 0):

On first load, 'mi-selected' class is not getting added to your code which is the reason for your problem. You can check in your slider js, what is actually the issue. And yes, you can follow the 'noconflict'/@Roy answer also to check if your issue has been resolved